# Найти наименьшее значение в массиве ключ - значение

Tags: php

Нужно получить наименьшее значение "price" в таком массиве. Можно ли это сделать без цикла? Допустим использовать функцию min();

```
$array[] = array(
        'name' => 'user_name',
        'price'=> 15
    );
    $array[] = array(
        'name' => 'user_name2',
        'price'=> 10
    );
```

Comment: `min(array_column($data, 'price'));` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo min(array_column($data, 'price'));
```